# Azure Search - Are multiple analyzers on single field like ElasticSearch possible?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm comparing Azure Search and ElasticSearch for features and performance.
I'm looking to see if I can have multiple analyzers per field.
In ElasticSearch I can do this

```
      "Name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "ingram",
        "fields": {
          "partial": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "customWhitespace",
            "boost": 2
          },
          "exact": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "customKeyword",
            "boost": 3
          }
        }
      },
```

Since both technologies are similar, I tried to replicate the same structure in Azure

```
    {
      "name": "text",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": "ingram",
      "fields": [
        {
            "name": "partial",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": true,
            "analyzer": "customWhitespace",
        }
        ]
    },
```

but got an error on index creation

```
The request is invalid. Details: definition : The field 'text' of type 
'Edm.String' cannot have sub-fields because it is not a complex type.
```

I found this post [Azure Search: Implementing Partial Word Search](https://medium.com/cloud-maker/azure-search-implementing-partial-word-search-c770cd052f39)
which seems to say that you have to create a secondary field and load the data into that a second time in order to provide the same functionality.

Is there a way to provide the same kind of functionality without having to load the data a second time into another field?  This just artificially increases my index size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two separate issues here.  The first is in the way that you created the index (or more specifically the fields).  In the index creation, you structured it to create an array of fields.  In Azure Cognitive Search, that is what we call a Complex Type of which you can find more [information here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-complex-data-types).  If you wanted to create multiple fields, you don't need to set those as a set fields within a complex type though.  You can just create them at the root of the index.

To you original, question, you can only like a single analyzer (or custom analyzer) to a single field.  That is the reason for the comment you made in your question about creating duplicate fields.  Given that it looks like you want to also apply custom boosting to different fields, it seems this approach would also allow you do to that.

Hope that helps, Liam