# Multiple analyzers for a single field in a search index of Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

We need two different types of search (based on user input), partial and exact for few fields that we have and for the same requirement, we require two different analyzers for each field to produce the required output.

Now, the problem is, I'm not able to configure 2 analyzers for a single field. The only option for me is to create two different indexes altogether and then query respective index based on the user input, but clearly, this is not the right solution, it is not scalable, mostly redundant data and takes almost double the space.

I'm trying to create a duplicate field in the same index with different analyzers and use the output of them based on the user input, but I'm not sure how I can configure that in the index. The name of the field is what is used to search for, during query time. Is there a possibility for me to have 2 different fields with different names, which actually point to one field but have different analyzers?

Comment: Are you using an indexer or directly pushing documents using the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 different fields with different names, which actually point to one field with two different analyzers. This can be done using field mappings in indexer definition.

1. I have created index as shown below,
   [image]
2. As highlighted in above screen shot, I have taken two new fields with name cont01 and cont02.
3. These two new fields will point to field merged_content with two different analyzers.
4. In indexer definition I have configured field mappings as shown below,
   [image]
5. Ran indexer and results are as shown below,
   [image]
   Reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59324309/azure-search-are-multiple-analyzers-on-single-field-like-elasticsearch-possibl)

Comment: The images are broken for me. Could you please check? Thanks

Comment: Images provided by me are not clear? kindly clarify

Comment: It's not visible for me, they're not loading.

Comment: There might be issue with your browser or cache. Try to clear and retry. From my side there is no issue